# Interactive admin shell for Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am experimenting with Kafka. I am able to get a basic cluster with Zookeeper and a broker running and produce/consume data.
Is there a interactive administration shell/cli for Kafka?
I would like to have one view of all the topics , the partitions of a topic, the produce/consume rates, how much data is persisted, etc.
I have searched online and looked in the installation. I couldn't find any administration utility.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka metrics might be exposed over JMX and explored in `jconsole`.

On each broker add following line somewhere in `kafka-server-start.sh` on Linux/MacOS:

```
export JMX_PORT=9999
```

or `kafka-server-start.bat` on Windows:

```
set JMX_PORT=9999
```

Note that most JMX metrics expose the state of local broker, so you'd have to connect to all brokers simultaneously to get the whole picture. So, it's more convenient to export necessary JMX metrics to the monitoring system of your choice (Ganglia/Graphite/Nagios/etc.).

Comment: Now i can see topics/partitions and some metrics. Thanks for this.

Comment: Also check jmx2graphite (https://github.com/logzio/jmx2graphite) to dump JMX into Graphite in one command line without installation nor hefty configuration

Answer (score 6):

There is [Kafka Web Console](https://github.com/claudemamo/kafka-web-console) and [Kafka Offset Monitor](https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor). Kafka Web Console may not have all what you want but in the future it will include what you're asking for.

Comment: yes, i downloaded kafka offset monitor. It is basic but a little useful. I didnt want to download the web console because of the database requirement. There should be a way to run it without having a db in the picture.

Comment: Kafka offset monitor has a database as well but it's not configurable. The default database with web console is embedded (H2) so you don't need to install one.

Comment: ok Claude, I will try the web console too and work with the default.

Comment: Sigh, Kafka Web Console & Kafka Offset Monitor are no longer supported :-(